# Which abilities do Drupal-specific Twig and Twig itself have to work with files?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm interested in the full list of all possible abilities Drupal-specific Twig has to work with files, i.e. reading, writing, copying, renaming etc. Including all the abilities Twig itself has regardless of CMS. So please don't remove the tag `Twig`.

Yet I just know about loading template partials like

```
{% include '@themename/header.html.twig' %}
```

It's an example of reading a file by its filesystem path

Can Drupal-specific Twig or Twig itself also rename a file? Or copy with renaming? And so on

Comment: Unsure what the question is here. Twig is a templating engine and doesn't have the ability to create/rename/edit files by default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending or including - what is better in Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051743/extending-or-including-what-is-better-in-twig)

Comment: @DarkBee Do you mean Twig can only read files and only templates/partials?

Comment: That is correct, you have `include`, `embed`, `extend`, `use` and `import`. The only files twig is able to "create" are the "compiled" templates in `PHP` if the cache is enabled

Comment: @DarkBee Could you post a link with information about the last you've mentioned, i.e. creating compiled templates in PHP? Especially Drupal-specific

Comment: That's addressed in the note below the [basic documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#basics). There is also the `cache`-tag, but isn't enabled by default - [cache](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/cache.html)